# I am using Cloud SQL on Google app engine. Once I add a new user in the console and re-deploy my app the new user can't seem to login?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, google-app-engine

When I add in a new user and password in the GCP console, refresh and wait, then re deploy and run my web app I can't login with that user. I can still login with my original test user (the first and only user thus far beside the 'postgres' admin. user)

Ive tried deleting and re-adding the same user.Ive tried adding yet another user and deploying - re attempting to login in again. Ive made sure Ive refreshed and waited for the change to take effect before re-deploying the web app . I have logged with my original user , log out and try login with the new user, also initially with the new user.I've scoured online for answers but surprisingly to no avail.

The main , outer, app.py file that has the user management/Auth code using Flask and flask_login functionality :

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import sys

#sys.path.append('/Users/crowledj/Mindfule/dash-flask-login/views/')
#sys.path.append('/Users/crowledj/Mindfule/dash-flask-login/flask_login/')

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__ , external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)


#server=app.server

app.css.append_css({'external_url': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css'})


from server import app, server
from flask_login import logout_user, current_user
import success, login, login_fd, logout
#import sqlalchemy

header = html.Div(
    className='header',
    children=html.Div(
        className='container-width',
        style={'height': '100%'},
        children=[
            html.Img(
                src='mindfule_company_logo.jpg',
                className='logo'
            ),
            html.Div(className='links', children=[
                html.Div(id='user-name', className='link'),
                html.Div(id='logout', className='link')
            ])
        ]
    )
)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        header,
        html.Div([
            html.Div(
                html.Div(id='page-content', className='content'),
                className='content-container'
            ),
        ], className='container-width'),
        dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
    ]
)


@app.callback(Output('page-content', 'children'),
              [Input('url', 'pathname')])
def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname == '/':
        return login.layout
    elif pathname == '/login':
        return login.layout
    elif pathname == '/success':
        if current_user.is_authenticated:
            print('returning success page from main app ...  \n')
            return success.layout
        else:
            return login_fd.layout
    elif pathname == '/logout':
        if current_user.is_authenticated:
            logout_user()
            return logout.layout
        else:
            return logout.layout
    else:
        return '404'


@app.callback(
    Output('user-name', 'children'),
    [Input('page-content', 'children')])
def cur_user(input1):
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return html.Div('Current user: ' + current_user.username)
        # 'User authenticated' return username in get_id()
    else:
        return ''


@app.callback(
    Output('logout', 'children'),
    [Input('page-content', 'children')])
def user_logout(input1):
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return html.A('Logout', href='/logout')
    else:
        return ''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True,port=8080,host= "foodmoodai.appspot.com")  #"0.0.0.0")  #
```

the only Postgres and SQL related code @ start of my 'success' page file :

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

import plotly.graph_objs as go

from textwrap import dedent as d

from flask import Flask
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from NutrientParser import parseNutrientStr_frmUser,parseResearch,parseFoodResearch,find_substring
from userMindfuleClasses import *
import PIL  
import urllib3
from PIL import Image
import json,os
import arrow


from server import app
from flask_login import current_user

import psycopg2
from datetime import datetime

timeStamp=datetime.now()

#db_user='test'
#db_pass='test1'
#db_name='foodnmood-db'
#INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME='foodmoodai:europe-west2:foodnmood-db'


from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData,create_engine
meta = MetaData()

#engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:Pollgorm1@/cloudsql/foodmoodai:europe-west2:foodnmood-db')
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:Pollgorm1@/?host=/cloudsql/foodmoodai:europe-west2:foodnmood-db')


mealnMoodwithTimesnFoods = Table(
    'mealnMoodwithTimesnFoods', meta, 
    Column('time', String, primary_key = True),
    Column('id', String), 
    Column('food_1', String), 
    Column('food_2', String),
    Column('food_3', String), 
    Column('mood', String), 

)

meta.create_all(engine)
```

I expect to be able to at least add a new user (which automatically has login permissions) and log in past the log in page when I redeploy the app after making this change in the GCP console.

Comment: Console mean postgresql (psql) console? Did you created user in postgresql and unable to login?

Comment: As @Vivek said, are you creating an user for your PostgreSQL database? and then you are trying to connect to the database with that user and you get an error? (if you do get an error, can you update your question with the message?).

Comment: I was . creating the user in the gcloud for psql Vivek and Mayeru yes.But its OK I just earloier realised the issue. I was using a local git clone  in flask for user authentication which I needed to update as well ,,...!

Comment: This can be closed , thanks so much for your help guys . So it turns out how I expected and worded the Q was not so correct.

Comment: Could you please post the solution as an answer, so it might help other people in the community?

Comment: Sure, as soon as I can ..

Answer (score 0):

The issue here turned out to actually be completely to do with a local authentication library I had installed from GitHub -  which uses 'flask_login' (flask_login==0.4.1 --> pip install flask-login==0.4.1).All I needed to do was update the new user and password in a local .txt file as well as on gcloud's cloud SQL console.